# Most efficient way to query a database and then remove entries from returned items

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have a app that allows you to follow peoples blog updates. I have a page where the user can choose who to follow. the people who can be followed are stored in a db ( Table name - Person) and when the user selects someone to follow that is also stored in the db ( Table name - Following).

The problem I have is when the user revisits the page to follow another person, what is the best way to query the database and only display people that the user is not following.

I am using Entity framework.

I have the following working. I need a where statement. `followBloggers` is returning a list of bloggers that the user is following and `Uow.People.GetPeople()` is returning all bloggers.

```
var followedBloggers = Uow.FollowBlogger.GetLinks(companyId).ToList();
return Uow.People.GetPeople().Select(p => new { p });
```

Comment: Can you please show your code for what objects are on your user class?

Comment: @IronMan84 i have updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming that Following has a FK to People on PersonID):

```
var followedIDs = user.followBloggers.Select(follow => follow.PersonID);
return Uow.People.GetPeople().Where(p => !followedIDs.Contains(p.PersonID));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
var AlreadyFollowed = currentUser.followBloggers.Select( f => f.Id);
Uow.People.GetPeople().Where( p => !AlreadyFollowed.Contains(p.Id));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. Can you look at the update and perhaps make a sugestion where i can implement your idea. Thanks

Comment: Now I have reformated my answer and its now pretty the same as stated by IronMan84